# CSS Animation Delay Issue

Tags: html, css

So I've been trying to create a site (as a project) with museums, and I tried adding some animation, and the animation works, but I tried putting a delay on it (I have 7 little images of museums that go from the bottom to the top as a bubble)

```
.muzee img{
    width: 60px;
    animation: muzee 7s linear infinite;
}

.muzee {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -70px;
}

@keyframes muzee{
    0%{
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50%{

        opacity: 1;
    }
    70%{

        opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(-80vh);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.muzee img:nth-chlid(1){
    animation-delay: 2s;
    width: 25px;
}
.muzee img:nth-chlid(2){
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.muzee img:nth-chlid(3){
    animation-delay: 3s;
    width: 25px;
}
.muzee img:nth-chlid(4){
    animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
.muzee img:nth-chlid(5){
    animation-delay: 3.25s;
}
.muzee img:nth-chlid(6){
    animation-delay: 6s;
    width: 20px;
}
.muzee img:nth-chlid(7){
    animation-delay: 7s;
    width: 35px;
}
```

Comment: hi, it looks like you may have a typo there `chlid` ( should be `child`)

Comment: Thank you, oopsie, I legit didn't see it, thanks!